# Large number of concurrent HTTP connections

Tags: erlang, elixir

I am very much new to Elixir (and Erlang), so please bear with me. I am trying to simulate a very large number of connections to a server. I want to wrap the following in a Task and run a large number of such tasks. Here is the pseudo code for the Task:

```
def connect() do
  conn = create_connection(url) # connect only once
  idle(conn)
end

def idle(conn) do
  http_post(conn, getbody()) #this will give a heartbeat after 1 minute
  idle(conn) # reconnect using existing connection
end
```

Here is the supervisor in which the Task is added as a child:

```
import Supervisor.Spec

children = [
  worker(Task, [], restart: :transient)
]
opts = [strategy: :simple_one_for_one, name: D.S]
Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
```

Each time a new connection is required, this gets called:
`Supervisor.start_child(D.S, [ fn -> connect() end ])`

I have used shotgun http client library. But the problem is I can make only around 8k connections. After that I get various errors like `File operation error: system_limit. Target: wxTextAttr.beam. Function: get_file. Process: code_server`.

I have two questions:

1. Why am I getting the above error?
2. Is there any other light weight HTTP client library that allows reuse of existing connection and doesn't hit any of the system limits when used in large number?

Comment: Probably ran out of sockets. Check `ulimit -n`

Comment: @Lol4t0 thanks! The Erlang VM was on a Windows machine. I shifted it to a linux one, and changed the ulimit. It works! Can you post it as an answer?

Comment: By the way, how to change ulimit in Windows?

Comment: Did you try apache benchmark tool https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html ?

Comment: See [this writeup](http://smallvoid.com/article/winnt-tcpip-max-limit.html) on options to configure windows tcp stack.